# Update other model after POST or UPDATE

Tags: loopback

I have a loopback model 'page', and with an admin panel you can post/edit/remove them.
I also have another model 'updates' that has 1 string. (random value)

I would like that each time something is posted, edited or removed, that the string of the other value changes.

I can create a new function to get data, but I have no idea how to edit (or hook?) an existing buildin function to update another model.

API example:
if there is an call: POST: /pages
then there should be an UPDATE: /updates

Comment: Can you provide some code to better understand that you want to do? Are you working with loopback 3 or 4?

Comment: If you are using LB3 check these docs: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html